# Format an Array by Removing Dynamic Associative Key

Tags: php, arrays

Need some help formatting this array properly:

Here is the dump of the array:

```
array (size=5)
  'Bank Deposit' => 
    array (size=13)
      'Payment Method' => string 'Bank Deposit' (length=12)
      0 => string 'Bank Deposit' (length=12)
      201704 => string '1200' (length=4)
      201705 => string '0' (length=1)
      201701 => string '0' (length=1)
      201706 => string '0' (length=1)
      201707 => string '0' (length=1)
      201612 => string '0' (length=1)
      201708 => string '0' (length=1)
      201602 => string '0' (length=1)
      201709 => string '0' (length=1)
      201702 => string '0' (length=1)
      201710 => string '0' (length=1)
  'Cash' => 
    array (size=13)
      'Payment Method' => string 'Cash' (length=4)
      0 => string 'Cash' (length=4)
      201704 => string '300' (length=3)
      201705 => string '120' (length=3)
      201701 => string '800' (length=3)
      201706 => string '800' (length=3)
      201707 => string '120' (length=3)
      201612 => string '800' (length=3)
      201708 => string '800' (length=3)
      201602 => string '12' (length=2)
      201709 => string '12' (length=2)
      201702 => string '0' (length=1)
      201710 => string '0' (length=1)
  'Cheque' => 
    array (size=13)
      'Payment Method' => string 'Cheque' (length=6)
      0 => string 'Cheque' (length=6)
      201704 => string '10' (length=2)
      201705 => string '0' (length=1)
      201701 => string '590' (length=3)
      201706 => string '590' (length=3)
      201707 => string '0' (length=1)
      201612 => string '0' (length=1)
      201708 => string '0' (length=1)
      201602 => string '231' (length=3)
      201709 => string '231' (length=3)
      201702 => string '0' (length=1)
      201710 => string '0' (length=1)
  'Mobile Money' => 
    array (size=13)
      'Payment Method' => string 'Mobile Money' (length=12)
      0 => string 'Mobile Money' (length=12)
      201704 => string '0' (length=1)
      201705 => string '0' (length=1)
      201701 => string '0' (length=1)
      201706 => string '0' (length=1)
      201707 => string '0' (length=1)
      201612 => string '0' (length=1)
      201708 => string '0' (length=1)
      201602 => string '0' (length=1)
      201709 => string '0' (length=1)
      201702 => string '150' (length=3)
      201710 => string '150' (length=3)
  '' => 
    array (size=13)
      'Payment Method' => null
      0 => null
      201704 => string '1510' (length=4)
      201705 => string '120' (length=3)
      201701 => string '1390' (length=4)
      201706 => string '1390' (length=4)
      201707 => string '120' (length=3)
      201612 => string '800' (length=3)
      201708 => string '800' (length=3)
      201602 => string '243' (length=3)
      201709 => string '243' (length=3)
      201702 => string '150' (length=3)
      201710 => string '150' (length=3)
```

QUESTION: How do I get rid of the 'Payment Method' and 0 keys in the array?

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

Table as it is: https://ibb.co/gW55g5

Splicing the value from offset 1: https://ibb.co/fogNTk

Splicing the value and key from offset 1: https://ibb.co/jgU98k

This removes the columns but then reindexes the keys!

```
<div class='box-body no-padding'>
                <table class='table cell-border' id='summary'><thead>
                <tr>

<?php 
        $temp = [];
        foreach($results as $k => $v){
            $temp[$v['Payment Method']] = $v;
                } foreach (array_splice($v,1) as $k => $v){
                    echo '<th>'.$k.'</th>';
            }
        var_dump($temp);

        }

?>

    </tr></thead>
<?php
        $temp = [];
        foreach($results as $k => $v){
            $temp[$v['Payment Method']] = $v;
                foreach (array_splice($v , 1) as $k => $v){
            echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I made an earlier post but it seemed to not get to the point but if you need any extra help in getting the picture you can see a more detailed question here: [Multidimensional Array Dynamic Columns Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286124/multidimensional-array-dynamic-columns-format). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = [
    'foo' =>
    [
        'unwanted' => 'something',
        0 => 'something else not wanted',
        '201704' => '23',

    ],
    'bar' =>
    [
        'unwanted' => 'something',
        0 => 'something else not wanted',
        '201703' => '47',

    ]
];

foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    unset($data[$k]['unwanted']);
    unset($data[$k][0]);
}

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    201704 => '23',
  ),
  'bar' => 
  array (
    201703 => '47',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hey, I literally was updating and answering the question myself, I got the same result as you. Thanks. Will give you the correct answer as you took your time to answer it thanks.

Comment: Tip: [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) accepts any number of variables, so you can write: `unset($data[$k]['unwanted'], $data[$k][0]);`. Better, you can pass the array by reference to the `foreach` loop: `foreach($data as &$v) { unset($v['unwanted'], $v[0]); }` *(this way you avoid a copy of the original array)*

Comment: Didn't know it accepted multiple variables, will add that in. Thanks